Issue booting newer Linux kernels with multiple VGA adaptors (ASPEED and AMD)
I built a custom server using Ubuntu 22.04 with a B650D4U server motherboard that takes a Ryzen CPU - and it worked perfectly.   I then upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04 and video output (which is on the VGA port) broke when using the supplied kernel (6.8.0).    Booting the Ubuntu 24.04 install with the older (5.15.0) kernel boots the system.
When booting with the new kernel, GRUB works, and then the screen goes blank.  No amount of playing with grub parameters seems to fix the issue (I tried a whole lot of things like nomodeset, text, various vga= options).
(As I have an otherwise working server, I am able to boot the new kernel and access the system over ssh)
Comparing the module sets loaded between the kernels I noted that the older kernel did not load the amdgpu module, while the newer module loaded the amdgpu module and its dependencies - however blacklisting the amdgpu module and its dependencies did not fix things.
(In both kernels), lspci | grep "VGA" outputs -
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 52)
0d:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raphael (rev c4)

The output of "grep ast " for dmesg from the new kernel is
[    3.400553] ast 0000:07:00.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    3.400648] ast 0000:07:00.0: Using default configuration
[    3.400650] ast 0000:07:00.0: AST 2600 detected
[    3.400680] ast 0000:07:00.0: [drm] Using ASPEED DisplayPort transmitter
[    3.400681] ast 0000:07:00.0: [drm] dram MCLK=396 Mhz type=1 bus_width=16
[    3.400815] [drm] Initialized ast 0.1.0 20120228 for 0000:07:00.0 on minor 0
[    3.401642] ast 0000:07:00.0: [drm] fb0: astdrmfb frame buffer device

Compared with the output from the old working kernel
[    5.675314] ast 0000:07:00.0: [drm] P2A bridge disabled, using default configuration
[    5.675316] ast 0000:07:00.0: [drm] AST 2600 detected
[    5.675320] ast 0000:07:00.0: [drm] Analog VGA only
[    5.675321] ast 0000:07:00.0: [drm] dram MCLK=396 Mhz type=1 bus_width=16
[    5.675531] [drm] Initialized ast 0.1.0 20120228 for 0000:07:00.0 on minor 0
[    5.753840] fbcon: astdrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    5.753900] ast 0000:07:00.0: [drm] fb0: astdrmfb frame buffer device

The command "dmesg | grep "vgaarb" on both kernels outputted the following (with the important exception of the last line as commented on further below) -
[    0.532715] pci 0000:07:00.0: vgaarb: setting as boot VGA device
[    0.532715] pci 0000:07:00.0: vgaarb: bridge control possible
[    0.532715] pci 0000:07:00.0: vgaarb: VGA device added: decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
[    0.532715] pci 0000:0d:00.0: vgaarb: bridge control possible
[    0.532715] pci 0000:0d:00.0: vgaarb: VGA device added: decodes=io+mem,owns=none,locks=none
[    0.532715] vgaarb: loaded
[    5.741803] ast 0000:07:00.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console

I expect the the issue relates to the first line on the new kernel, and fixing this will fix the problem -
  [    3.400553] ast 0000:07:00.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console

As this system is a server in a data center, and as most servers use VGA for output I really do want output over VGA, so that if TSHTF I am not further hampered by the inability to see the console output.  (Also, it seems that the KVM console feeds its input from the ASPEED VGA device - not a surprise as the ASPEED VGA device is, as I understand it, part of the BMC)
Can anyone help me with this?  (I posit I am asking how I can prevent the vgaarb console from being deactivated for the ast device?)

I don't have an 'answer' but to clarify, the errant AMD GPU is part of an APU and not a discrete card?

@JourneymanGeek - As I understand it For the AST interface its more like a discrete card then an APU.  The AST interface is, as best I understand, a BMC controller with its own chipset.  The amd "gpu" is on the CPU die, not a discrete card.  I don't think thats being used though.

Filtering the kernel log (i.e. relying on dmesg | grep ... ) removes the context of each message, and may conceal salient messages if you fail to choose the relevant search term(s). Have you tried comparing the boot logs from both kernels using sdiff (on a wide terminal screen)? (Removing timestamps will improve the comparison results.)

@sawdust Thank you for the thought.  I've done this now.  Displaying things this was helpful in as much as it appears to show that the new kernel is, after disabling the VGA console, using the "DisplayPort Transmitter" as the framebuffer and presumably throwing stuff onto that.   I can't see a way to disable this in the ast module though :(

Any luck with that @davidgo? I am having the same issue.

@AlexRecheMartinez Nope.   I gave up in the end and just stuck a label on the system to remind future me of this potential pitfall if I ever need a console.
